# Графы, компоненты связности, питон

Tags: python, графы

Мой код прошел не все тесты(( а что не так? вот задача https://informatics.msk.ru/mod/statements/view.php?id=256&chapterid=111540#1

Дан неориентированный невзвешенный граф. Необходимо посчитать количество его компонент связности и вывести их.

Входные данные
Во входном файле записано два числа N
и M
(0 < N
≤ 100000, 0 ≤ M
≤ 100000). В следующих M
строках записаны по два числа i
и j
(1 ≤ i
, j
≤ N
), которые означают, что вершины i
и j
соединены ребром.

Выходные данные
В первой строчке выходного файла выведите количество компонент связности. Далее выведите сами компоненты связности в следующем формате: в первой строке количество вершин в компоненте, во второй - сами вершины в произвольном порядке.

```
def am(now):
    visited.append(now)
    new_visited.append(now)
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if i not in visited and i in graph[now]:
            am(i)
    
n,m = map(int, input().split())
graph = [0] * (n+1)
for i in range(n+1):
    graph[i] = []
for i in range(m):
    k,w = map(int, input().split())
    graph[k].append(w)
    graph[w].append(k)
visited = []
new_visited = []
new_new_visited = []
while len(visited) != n:
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        if i not in visited:
            am(i)
            break
    new_new_visited.append(new_visited)
    new_visited = []
print(len(new_new_visited))
for i in new_new_visited:
    print(len(i))
    print(*i)
```

Comment: Проблема в компиляторе

Comment: в смысле? Какие-то тесты прошел, какие-то нет

Comment: какое замечательное предложение, я согласна)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Проблемы

1. `i not in visited` выполяются медленно, за линейное время, так как `visited` - список. Замена на множество ускоряет алгоритм в *N* раз.
2. Вот этот цикл делает *N* итераций:

   ```
       for i in range(1, n+1):
           if i not in visited and i in graph[now]:
               am(i)
   ```

   А этот выполняет ту же работу за `len(graph[now])` итераций:

   ```
       for i in graph[now]:
           if i not in visited:
               am(i)
   ```

   Ещё одно ускорение в *N* раз.
3. Цикл `for` начинает поиск с начала графа для каждой новой компоненты связности - сложность *NK* для *K* компонент:

   ```
   while len(visited) != n:
       for i in range(1, n+1):
           if i not in visited:
               am(i)
               break
       new_new_visited.append(new_visited)
       new_visited = []
   ```

   А этот цикл всю работу делает за время *N* вне зависимости от *K*:

   ```
   for i in range(1, n+1):
       if i not in visited:
           am(i)
           new_new_visited.append(new_visited)
           new_visited = []
   ```

   В худшем случае *K = N* - ускорение в *N* раз.
4. Функция `am` рекурсивна. Глубина рекурсии в Питоне обычно тысяча вызовов, иногда две или три тысячи. Если в графе найдется цикл длиной десять тысяч, глубины рекурсии не хватит. Шестнадцатый тест упадет.

   Функцию можно переписать без рекурсии, на стеке:

   ```
   def am(start):
       visited.add(start)
       stack = [start]
       while stack:
           now = stack.pop()
           new_visited.append(now)
           for i in graph[now]:
               if i not in visited:
                   visited.add(i)
                   stack.append(i)
   ```

### Код

Ваш код с четырьмя изменениями проходит все тесты:

```
def am(start):
    visited.add(start)
    stack = [start]
    while stack:
        now = stack.pop()
        new_visited.append(now)
        for i in graph[now]:
            if i not in visited:
                visited.add(i)
                stack.append(i)

    
n, m = map(int, input().split())
graph = [0] * (n+1)
for i in range(n+1):
    graph[i] = []
for i in range(m):
    k, w = map(int, input().split())
    graph[k].append(w)
    graph[w].append(k)

visited = set()
new_visited = []
new_new_visited = []

for i in range(1, n+1):
    if i not in visited:
        am(i)
        new_new_visited.append(new_visited)
        new_visited = []

print(len(new_new_visited))
for i in new_new_visited:
    print(len(i))
    print(*i)
```

### Ещё код

Нет глобальных переменных, генераторы вместо списков - xотя это дело вкуса. `visited` не обязан быть множеством, список булевых флагов тоже работает:

```
def components(graph):
    visited = [False] * len(graph)

    def traverse(i):
        visited[i] = True
        stack = [i]
        while stack:
            i = stack.pop()
            yield i
            for j in graph[i]:
                if not visited[j]:
                    visited[j] = True
                    stack.append(j)

    for i in range(1, len(graph)):
        if not visited[i]:
            yield tuple(traverse(i))


def main():
    n, m = map(int, input().split())
    graph = tuple([] for _ in range(n + 1))
    for _ in range(m):
        i, j = map(int, input().split())
        graph[i].append(j)
        graph[j].append(i)

    answer = tuple(components(graph))

    print(len(answer))
    for c in answer:
        print(len(c))
        print(*c)


main()
```